# deleting pop3 mail account not possible

Tags: email, 4.4-kitkat, pop3

I want to delete a pop3 mail account, but I can't find the option to do that. All I can do is synchronize! I can find the option with my Google account, but I don't want to delete that. I use Android 4.4.2 on a Nexus 7.

Comment: Is this on the GMail app, or the Email app?

Comment: I want to delete an Email app account.

Comment: If you add a Google account in sync, it will always show up in the GMail app. The best thing you can do is to uncheck/disable the Mail sync while retaining the other syncs that you need. However, you can still refresh the GMail content by refreshing manually.

Comment: @geffchang: I don't mind the GMail sync, I just want to get rid of the Email sync. I disabled it for now, but I'm wondering why you can't delete it.

Comment: So it shows up in both the Email app and the GMail app?

Comment: @geffchang: I think the GMail sync doesn't even exist. I use a different app for my emails.

Comment: So you are using the Email app? If not the Email app, what app are you using for emails?

Comment: @geffchang: It's a custom app from the email provider I'm using.

Comment: Well, I suppose you should be asking them how to delete that email account.

Comment: No, I don't want to delete that custom email account. That's the only one I want to use! I want to delete the android email account. The symbol is a white envelope with some yellow parts.

Comment: @geffchang: [Here](http://www.geeksuper.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/android-email-apps.png) is a picture of the app. I think it's the standard Android email app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [geffchang](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/5342/geffchang)'s [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65155/deleting-pop3-mail-account-not-possible/65195#65195) didn't work, you can try this at a last resort.

System setting > Apps > ALL > Email > Deactivate.

However, this not only removes the account you wanted to remove but also all other accounts.

Comment: I didn't have that option available.  For me on a Nexus 5 running Kit Kat it was `System settings > Apps > All > Email > Clear data`.

Answer (score 1):

Google stuffed up the labeling here - the way to do it is to go to your phones main Settings.  Under Accounts you will find IMAP (should have been labeled "Email"). Tap IMAP. Then tap the account you want to remove, and then tap the dots at the top right and choose Remove account.  Done.

Comment: Your answer is basically the same as geffchang's [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65155/deleting-pop3-mail-account-not-possible/65195#65195).

Answer (score 0):

`System Settings > Accounts > IMAP > [email account] > top-right menu: Remove account`.

Comment: There is no "Remove account", only "Sync account".

Comment: @gartenriese Are there any other email accounts in the Email app? Because if it's the only Email account there, I can recommend something for you to try.

Comment: It's the only account.

Comment: @gartenriese `System settings > Apps > ALL > Email > [Clear Data], [Clear cache]`

Comment: @gartenriese Any updates from your end?

Comment: Ok, this didn't work. I just deactivated it, that should stop it, I guess. Now it's not listed under accounts anymore.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys I could get rid of my email account in email app of android 4.4.2 : app>all>email>clear cached data as well as memory. It removed all email accounts from email app, and then I added which I wanted to keep.